# Increase Cell for next file to be Upload in Google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I did try some couple thinks but i realy need help on this one! First I am a beginner and I usualy speak French ...Sorry my explain could be hard some time to understand...

But, I create a Ui showModalDialog where I can Upload picture via the App script. Actualy it works, I received my file in a Cell on my spreadSheet. The problem is when i want to Upload others picture... I want it to go on the next Cell below. And if it's possible to stop to 6 picture...

Here is where I block!

```
function uploadFileToDrive(file) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Received Files";
    var folder =DriveApp.getFolderById('1M0cMzJd6yD6f….iJZyaCrBw_U5k');

    var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
        bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file),
        file = folder.createFile(blob),
        filelink=file.getUrl() ;

    // where to set data

    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('Tableau');
   var headRow =  6;
   var headers = sheet.getRange(7,9,1).setValue(filelink);

// here I need to increase Cell for the next filelink entry….
```

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.getLastRow()` to find the last row with data in your selected sheet and use that in the `.getRange()`

This line will paste the URL in column 9 of the next available row.

```
var headers = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,9).setValue(filelink);
```

Comment: It replace the value in the first cell but it don't increase to next one.  :(   thx